# Forward Route53 to another DNS provider

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, dns-zone, amazon-route53, cloudflare

I have many customer websites set up using Route53 as the DNS provider. I've switched over to using CloudFlare DNS for newer websites and would like to migrate these older sites over to the same DNS without them needing to update the nameservers in their domain registrar.

In Route53 you can update the `NS` and `SOA` records. Is it possible to use these to forward all DNS requests from Route53 to CloudFlare DNS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> without them needing to update the nameservers in their domain registrar.

This is impossible.

To resolve the names, at some point registry authoritative nameservers will be consulted. They, and only they, will tell anyone which are the appropriate authoritative nameservers for the domains.

And to change what is published by the registry nameservers you have to go through the currently sponsoring domain name registrar of each domain name.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible, but in the general case,  an extremely bad idea.

If the DNS records set for your clients zones (at the registrar, not Route53)  are under your control and not ones given by Route53, you can update the A records associated with those name servers to point them to Cloudflare (but it sounds like this is not possible from what you have said and my understanding of route53 defaults)

Answer (score 0):

Route53 do not support export you can use [open source cli53](https://github.com/barnybug/cli53) to export your configuration

Comment: @Mike also check https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/migrating for migrating